# Can't find Sharepoint timerjob service among process to attach

Tags: visual-studio, timer-jobs, visual-studio-2012, debugging, owstimer

I would like to attach Visual Studio to OWSTIMER service to debug the execution of a sharepoint timer job, but the service stopped to appear among services to attach in Visual Studio. Any idea why ?

EDIT : check "show processes from all users"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **Show processes from all users**

[image]